# @Mapping List in Java

Tags: java, mapping, mapper

How to map a List with @Mapping?

I have a method in an interface that maps from a source DTO to a destination DTO

```
@Mapping(target = "group", source = "group")
@Mapping(target = "label", source = **???**)
@Mapping(target = "usersJobs", source = **???**)
UserResponse fromUserInfo(UserInfo user);
```

It's necessary to map the attributes from the **"params"** from **UserInfo** into the second **"label"** parameter:

as a result, the **"label"** attribute should look like this:

```
 "label": ["email_1", "123@gmail.com"]
```

And next it's necessary to map from the **"jobs"** from **UserInfo** into the third **"usersJobs"** parameter.

I didn't find suitable parameters in the documentation of this annotation.
Please tell me how can this be done?

DTO **UserInfo** looks like this:

```
public class UserInfo {
   @NotNull
   private String group;

   @NotNull
   private List<UserParams> params;

   @NotNull
   private List<UserUpdatedParams> jobs;
}
```

DTO **UserResponse** looks like this:

```
public class UserResponse {
   @NotNull
   private String group;

   @NotNull
   private List<Label> label;

   @NotNull
   private List<UsersJobs> usersJobs;
}
```

Comment: Unless the parsing of your `annotations` is what you are asking, please show the actual code and not just the skeletal definitions. Also provide concrete examples of before and after with sample data